# Typescript - recursive function

Tags: typescript

I have created recursive (rec) function inside `setBinary` method in typescript. But some reason it is not working in typescript but working in Angular.

How to convert the following angular to typescript.

While running gives an error "rec is not a function"

```
setBinary(rowId, vId, data) {          
   let pri;
    let pvi;
    let rec;


    rec (pri, pvi) {
        let latest = [];
        if (this.copyColumns[pri]) {
            this.copyColumns[pri].values[pvi].active = true;          

           let  x = this.copyColumns[pri].values[pvi]
            rec(x.pri, x.pvi)
        }
    };

    rec(data.pri, data.pvi)

}
```

Comment: `rec` must be declared a function, if this code is to run in either typescript or javascript

Answer (score 1):

Once you declare your function setBinary and your function rec, you have code which will compile.

```
function setBinary(rowId, vId, data) {          
    let pri;
    let pvi;

    let rec = function (pri, pvi) {
        let latest = [];
        if (this.copyColumns[pri]) {
            this.copyColumns[pri].values[pvi].active = true;          

           let  x = this.copyColumns[pri].values[pvi]
           rec(x.pri, x.pvi)
        }
    };

    rec(data.pri, data.pvi)
}
```